# Showing an account's open cases on another website?

Tags: api, case, account

I've built a support portal for our clients. Using SF's built-in portal wasn't really an option. I want to somehow show open cases for a particular account. On the website, we store the company names written exactly as the account names are on SF. Is there a way I could make a call to the SF API, lookup open cases for a given account, and list them out?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but I'd highly advise against using the Account Name as the key to link with your external website.  Two better options would be to either lookup the Account's Salesforce ID and store it in your external app or to add an external id field on Account and store your external apps account id in Salesforce.

Comment: Why do you say that? If the spelling is exact shouldn't it be no different than using the SF ID?

Comment: @Akor - Yes, but users can change the Name of the account, business practices may dictate a different naming convention, etc. You should always have an unchanging external ID to link between systems to minimize maintenance and ensure there is no chance of a mix up. Using the name is the easy route that could come back to bit you. It may look good now but the future is not defined

Comment: Also, keep in mind that SOQL text comparisons are case insensitive which adds an extra layer of complication if trying to do exact string matches.